# Download WhatsApp location file on Twilio API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I use Twilio API for WhatsApp messages. I send location messages but i can`t get this message on my server.

{ media: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/my_account_sid/Messages/message_sid/Media.json' },

I recieved this uri on my server in response message. When I get https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/my_account_sid/Messages/message_sid/Media url it shows 404 error : The requested resource "my_uri" was not found.
 How do I get location file?